# get json encoded value by jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
HTML:



  <input type="text" class="hide text" id="scharge" value="[{" servicecharge":{"id":"1","pieces":"2","discount":"50"}},{"servicecharge":{"id":"3","pieces":"3","discount":"60"}},{"servicecharge":{"id":"4","pieces":"4","discount":"70"}},{"servicecharge":{"id":"6","pieces":"1","discount":"0"}}]"="" style="display: none;">
```

How to get the value of `id="scharge"` ?

my jquery is :

```
  var sc = $('#scharge').val();
//  var scs = $.parseJSON(sc);

  console.log(sc);
```

but it shows the following response:

```
[{
```

Comment: Why does this surprise you? That's what the value of your input is set to: `value="[{"`

Comment: you need to escape the `"` occurrences within the value attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace double quote `"` with single quote `'`

```
 <input type="text" class="hide text" id="scharge" value='[{" servicecharge":{"id":"1","pieces":"2","discount":"50"}},{"servicecharge":{"id":"3","pieces":"3","discount":"60"}},{"servicecharge":{"id":"4","pieces":"4","discount":"70"}},{"servicecharge":{"id":"6","pieces":"1","discount":"0"}}]"' style="display: none;">

var sc = $('#scharge').val();

console.log(sc);
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/68jnoemg/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the JSON encoded data in single-quotes to assign it to the `<input>` value:

```
<input type="text" class="hide text" id="scharge" value='[{"servicecharge":{"id":"1","pieces":"2","discount":"50"}},{"servicecharge":{"id":"3","pieces":"3","discount":"60"}},{"servicecharge":{"id":"4","pieces":"4","discount":"70"}},{"servicecharge":{"id":"6","pieces":"1","discount":"0"}}]' style="display: none;">
Single quote                                            ^ and...>>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                         here ^
```